# How do I Continuous resample Pandas DataFrame without error

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I am resampling tick data from a broker and converting it into 30Sec interval data.
I am continuously resampling the same data every 30 sec. The data earlier resampled data is over written with a new resampled data. I expect the [-1] row to be new but the [-2] row value should remain unchanged (i.e it should be [-1] of earlier resample). However my [-2] values changes. Why is that so. Please see numbers and code and advice what is the issue and how to sort it out.

Code

```
  df=ticks['price'].resample(interval, label='right', closed='right').ohlc().dropna()
```

Output

```
 ts
    2021-09-24 15:08:30    98.75
    2021-09-24 15:09:00    97.75
 --------------------------------------- 2021-09-24 15:09:30.014828
    ts
    2021-09-24 15:09:00    98.0              
    2021-09-24 15:09:30    99.9
 --------------------------------------- 2021-09-24 15:10:00.012323
    ts
    2021-09-24 15:09:30    99.8
    2021-09-24 15:10:00    99.0
   --------------------------------------- 2021-09-24 15:10:30.000049
    ts
    2021-09-24 15:10:00     99.4
    2021-09-24 15:10:30    100.9
```

Another sample data now for 15 Seconds resampling. I have provided comments

```
--------------------------------------- 2021-09-24 15:29:15.005023
                     close        
ts                                   
2021-09-24 15:28:45  59.15          [-3]
2021-09-24 15:29:00  58.95          [-2]
2021-09-24 15:29:15  59.00          [-1]
--------------------------------------- 2021-09-24 15:29:30.013615
                     close        
ts                                   
2021-09-24 15:29:00  58.95          [-3]    
2021-09-24 15:29:15  58.95          [-2]    (Earlier was 59.00)
2021-09-24 15:29:30  59.40          [-1]
 --------------------------------------- 2021-09-24 15:29:45.000223
                     close        
ts                                   
2021-09-24 15:29:15  58.95      [-3] (Now remain unchanged) and continues to be same in subsequent run
2021-09-24 15:29:30  59.55          [-2]    (earlier was 59.40)
2021-09-24 15:29:45  59.80          [-1]
```

Comment: Can YOU provide a minimal set of data for playback?

Comment: This is continuous tick data I am maintaining a SQL database. It would be difficult to give data since it shall be a snapshot and not a stream data. The snapshot data shall not show this error since it is not expanding in real time.  And surprising is the [-3], [-4] and beyond remain same in two runs. The issue is only for [-1] value of resample data.